# Настройка доставки в WooCommerce на WordPress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Привязывается ли почтовый индекс при выборе страны? То есть что бы человек при выборе страны Польша, не смог ввести почтовый индекс России к примеру. Или что нужно для этого сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете сделать произвольную валидацию при оформление заказа по своим правилам с помощью хука [woocommerce_after_checkout_validation](https://wp-kama.ru/plugin/woocommerce/hook/woocommerce_after_checkout_validation)

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'custom_validation_postcode', 25, 2 );
 
function custom_validation_postcode( $fields, $errors ){

    // тут ставите свои правила на валидацию индекса в зависимости от страны на поля $fields[ 'billing_country' ]  и $fields[ 'billing_postcode' ]

    if ( $fields[ 'billing_country' ] &&  $fields[ 'billing_postcode' ]){
        $errors->add( 'validation', 'неправильный индекс' );
    }
 
}
```